# iOS send tweet with fabric without compose tweets

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, twitter, twitter-fabric

I want send tweet but i do not want to use compose tweets.

```
TWTRComposer *composer = [[TWTRComposer alloc] init];

[composer setText:@"just setting up my Fabric"];
[composer setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"fabric"]];

[composer showWithCompletion:^(TWTRComposerResult result) {
    if (result == TWTRComposerResultCancelled) {
        NSLog(@"Tweet composition cancelled");
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Sending Tweet!");
    }
}];
```

https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/compose this method display some pop up screen, i want to send tweet instant how can i do this with fabric api ?  this type is possible ?

This code part not work with fabric

```
 ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType withCompletionHandler:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)
     {
         if(granted)
         {
             NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

             if ([accountsArray count] > 0)
             {
                 ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];

                 TWRequest *postRequest = [[TWRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://upload.twitter.com/1/statuses/update_with_media.json"] parameters:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.textViewOutlet.text forKey:@"status"] requestMethod:TWRequestMethodPOST];

                 [postRequest addMultiPartData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) withName:@"media" type:@"multipart/png"];
                 [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

                 [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error)
                  {
                      //show status after done
                      NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP response status: %i", [urlResponse statusCode]];
                      NSLog(@"Twiter post status : %@", output);
                  }];
             }
         }
     }];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/nst/STTwitter

i used this API , easier than fabric :)

```
[_twitter postStatusUpdate:@"tweet text" inReplyToStatusID:nil latitude:nil longitude:nil placeID:nil displayCoordinates:nil trimUser:nil successBlock:nil errorBlock:nil];
```

very easy to send tweet without composer may be this one help someone ...

Comment: are you tried above code i am using but i am getting Domain=STTwitterTwitterErrorDomain Code=220 "Your credentials do not allow access to this resource." UserInfo=0x7ff4bb5a2720 {NSLocalizedDescription=Your credentials do not allow access to this resource., NSUnderlyingError=0x7ff4bb598c10 "HTTP Status 403: Forbidden"

Comment: You have to get permission first

Comment: how to get permissions? I enabled Allow this application to be used to Sign in with Twitter and change the permissions Read, Write and Access direct messages.

Comment: Have you got twitter application ? You should use `consumerKeyTextField` and `consumerSecretTextField`

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
func tweet(userId: String) {
        let client = TWTRAPIClient(userID: userId)

        let error: NSErrorPointer = NSErrorPointer()
        let url: String = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"
        let message: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
            "status" : "Sample Tweet Tweet!"
        ]

        let preparedRequest: NSURLRequest = client.URLRequestWithMethod("POST", URL: url, parameters: message, error: error)

        client.sendTwitterRequest(preparedRequest) { (response, data, jsonError) -> Void in
            do {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]
                NSLog("%@", json)
                print("Tweet post!")
            } catch {
                print("json error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

You must first get the userId of the user. If you're using the manual button registration use this:

```
func tweet(userId: String) {
        let client = TWTRAPIClient(userID: userId)

        let error: NSErrorPointer = NSErrorPointer()
        let url: String = "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/update.json"
        let message: [NSObject : AnyObject] = [
            "status" : "Sample Tweet Tweet!"
        ]

        let preparedRequest: NSURLRequest = client.URLRequestWithMethod("POST", URL: url, parameters: message, error: error)

        client.sendTwitterRequest(preparedRequest) { (response, data, jsonError) -> Void in
            do {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]
                NSLog("%@", json)
                print("Tweet post!")
            } catch {
                print("json error: \(error)")
            }
        }
    }
```

Sorry I wrote this code using Swift.

Comment: Thanks... do you have this for Swift 3?